# Open Directory over SSL / Mobile Accounts not working on Snow Leopard Server

Tags: mac-osx, mac-osx-server, openldap, opendirectory

I have a fully updated Mac OS X server 10.6.8 running on a Mac mini which I have open directory running on.

I have 2 problems with the setup that the manual doesn't deal with and I can find any solutions online:

## 1 Mac OS X Snow Leopard/Lion clients will not connect over SSL

I have followed Apple's instructions to import the servers certificate into the client machines and ensured that the command line "ldapsearch" connects just fine.  Firewall is also wide open for testing.  ldapsearch does seem to suggest that the server might be stuck on the LDAP port and not the LDAPS port.  The following works:

```
ldapsearch -v -x -H ldaps://<host> -b <search-base>
ldapsearch -v -x -H ldap://<host> -b <search-base>
```

But this doesn't:

```
ldapsearch -v -x -h <host> -p 636 -b <search-base>
```

Mac OS X also connects fine and authenticates as expected if SSL is turned off in Directory Utility.

## 2 I can't configure mobile accounts

I want to configure primarily mobile accounts as most client computers are laptops, however unlike as is suggested in the documentation, Workgroup Manager has no options to allow mobile accounts and configure sync settings for them.  The only settings I can find for this are under Active Directory, but I don't want to run a Microsoft server for a bunch of Macs plus I have already made the investment in a Mac hardware/software solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which guide did you follow up, so for the sake of archives:
[Apple's KB article HT4183](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4183)

To configure mobile accounts:

1. Create LDAP users in WM
2. select requested user in WM and click Preferences button
3. Choose Mobility icon
4. Set Always to create a new mobile account as requested
5. Set sync options

HTH
Robert